# Preposition change like "depend on" -> "independent of"

Tags: prepositions, negation

I'd like to know if, in English, there are more cases when the preposition changes for the negation (or eventually with some other change of gramatical context), the same or similar to "on" -> "of" with "independent"

Comment: There are several words which _can_, sometimes, take a preposition in the positive but never to my knowledge take one in the negative. I'm thinking of 'block up'/'unblock' and 'lit up'/'unlit' for instance but the nearest I can get to one where a preposition changes with negation, and even then the  prepositions are not always used, is the word 'shipped' where we can say 'shipped aboard' or 'shipped onto' but the negative is 'unshipped from'. It's probable that someone will prove me wrong so I've posted this as a comment.

Comment: I don't follow you. "Depend" is a verb and "independent" is an adjective, the latter typically taking an of phrase complement.

Comment: @BillJ I prefere adjectives, but so far I do not care for word cathegory.  _Something_ _depends_ _on_ _circumstances_ versus _manufacturers_ _are_ _dependent_ _on_ _their_ _supplies_ [link](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/be-dependent-on-upon-something) for example. The feature I am interested in is the change of the preposition when negation is introduced. _independent_ _of_ _the_ _observer_  [link](https://www.lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/dependent-on-upon-for/) [negation link](https://www.lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/independent-of-from-in-for-on/)